# How to show value created using setx in current cmd window?

Tags: batch-file, window, setx

I'm creating a .bat script that sets a variable using setx based on dynamic content.  I would like to echo back to the user what the new value has been set to.  I know from the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) that the variable is not available in the current window but will be available in newly opened windows.  Is there any way to confirm what the value has been set to and echo it back to the user (without opening a new window)?

Example is shown below.

[image]

Comment: After the `setx`, on the next line, just add `set "fou=This is Foo" `

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to read some source of truth rather than rely on assigning the same value to a different local variable and echo the local variable.

Comment: sorry for the different name, just typo error. You have the value you want to set, then you store it in registry via setx and store it in environment variable via set command. Just as simple as it. Or do it backwards, store the value in environment variable and then use that variable in the setx command

Answer (score 3):

When you use setx, the information is added directly to the registry, so just check the registry key.

In your case you were defining the content for the User Environment, which is located under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe foo "\"This is foo\""
For /F "Tokens=2*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\Environment" /V "foo"') Do @Echo=%H
```

Example in use:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try and let you know how I make out.  Thanks ! :)